# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message' when calling from command line

Tags: python, arguments

I am struggling to pass some arguments from the command line, so far the code looks like this:

```
class DeviceManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.network_ip = self.__get_network_ip__()
        self.devices = self.__get_devices__()
        self.sort_by("id")
    ...other methods such as pick_by_rangeID(f,t)...
```

This is the file Tool.py:

```
    import argparse
    from Device_Manager import*
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        dm = DeviceManager()
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        
        parser.add_argument("method", help ="method to call")
        parser.add_argument("-f", type = int, help ="from")
        parser.add_argument("-t", type = int, help ="to")
        args = parser.parse_args()
    
        if args.method == "sbID":
            dm.pick_by_range_ID(args.f,args.t)
```

And I am expecting to call it from the command line as: `python Tool.py sbID -f 5 -t 6`, which leads me to the error: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'`, as far as I have read, this happens when an object is initialized with missing arguments of its class.
For my surprise, if I run the method directly as bellow, the exception doesn't occurs.

```
dm = DeviceManager()
devs = dm.pick_by_range_ID(5,6)
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: addition of the `pick_by_rangeID` method:

```
 def pick_by_range_ID(self,from_ID = 0, to_ID = 999999) -> list:
        selected = []
        for dev in self.devices:
            id = dev.deviceID
            if id >= from_ID and id <= to_ID:
                selected.append(dev)
        if len(selected) == 0:
            raise ArgumentError("There are no IDs in that range.")
        return selected
```

Comment: Can you post your full pick_by_rangeID function on init?

Comment: @Luffli there was a little error in the post above, the method pick is NOT called on the init.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
The problem is at the line:

```
raise ArgumentError("There are no IDs in that range.")
```

ArgumentError takes two arguments `(class) ArgumentError(argument: Action | None, message: str)`

I solved by doing this:

```
raise ArgumentError(None, "There are no IDs in that range.")
```